# Getting Command failed with exit code when running substrate-parachain-template version polkadot-v1.0.0 with zombienet

Tags: polkadot, substrate-parachain-template, zombienet

I am getting the below error when I build and run `substrate-parachain-template` using zombienet. I am using the latest release (master branch of `substate-parachain-template`) which uses the latest substrate branch `polkadot-v1.0.0`.
I was able to run a relay chain and parachain network successfully using the older branch `polkadot-v0.9.43`. But  when I cloned the latest (master branch, which uses substrate branch `polkadot-v1.0.0`) I get the error below. I have also attached my Zombienet config after the error.
This error only happens with branch `v1.0.0` of `substrate-parachain-template`

```
Error:       Error: Command failed with exit code 1: bash -c binaries/parachain-template-node-v1.0.0 export-genesis-state --chain zn-db/template-rococo-1000-rococo-local.json > zn-db/cfg/genesis-state-1000 && binaries/parachain-template-node-v1.0.0 export-genesis-wasm --chain zn-db/template-rococo-1000-rococo-local.json > zn-db/cfg/genesis-wasm-1000
Error: Service(Client(Backend("IO error: While lock file: /Users/me/Library/Application Support/parachain-template-node-v1.0.0/chains/local_testnet/db/full/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable")))
```

I ran zombenet with this command

```
zombienet-macos -p native -d zn-db spawn ./zombienet-config.toml
```

Zomebienet config

```
[settings]
timeout = 1000

[relaychain]
default_command = "binaries/polkadot-v1.0.0"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ] 
chain = "rococo-local"

    [[relaychain.nodes]]
    name = "alice"
    validator = true
    ws_port = 9900

    [[relaychain.nodes]]
    name = "bob"
    validator = true

    [[relaychain.nodes]]
    name = "charlie"
    validator = true

    [[relaychain.nodes]]
    name = "dave"
    validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 1000
cumulus_based = true
add_to_genesis = true
chain = "template-rococo"

    [parachains.collator]
    command = "binaries/parachain-template-node-v1.0.0"
    name = "parachain-A-1000-collator01"
    ws_port = 9910
    args = ["--log=xcm=trace,pallet-assets=trace"]

[[parachains]]
id = 1001
add_to_genesis = true
cumulus_based = true

    [parachains.collator]
    command = "binaries/parachain-template-node-v1.0.0"
    name = "parachain-B-1001-collator01"
    ws_port = 9920
    args = ["--log=xcm=trace,pallet-assets=trace"]


[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"


[[hrmp_channels]]
sender = 1000
recipient = 1001 
max_capacity = 8
max_message_size = 512

[[hrmp_channels]]
sender = 1001
recipient = 1000
max_capacity = 8
max_message_size = 512
```

Comment: Hi @Neo, can you please rm/mv this directory (/Users/me/Library/Application Support/parachain-template-node-v1.0.0/chains/local_testnet) and try again?

Comment: @pepoviola I tried to do that, but found out that the directory does not even exist. It only exists up until /Users/yusufkelo/Library/Application Support/ , After /Application Support/ the remaining directories never existed

Comment: Quick update, there is a [tracking issue](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/1237). I can reproduce the error and as workaround you can run the network with the flag `-c 1` (to use single concurrency for spawning the nodes)

Answer (score 2):

quick workaround for this issue (as described here https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/1237#issuecomment-1675507189), is to run zombienet with concurrency set to 1.

```bash
zombienet-macos -p native -c 1-d zn-db spawn ./zombienet-config.toml
```

This should work as expected, until we review the locking issue.
Thanks!